# SendGrid - How to send Zip folder with multiple files using Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email via SendGrid/PHP with zip folder attached to email. the variable `$attachments` is an array contains list of zip folders.

```
public static function send_mail($to = "info@example.co.za", $subject = "Testing", $templateId, $templateData = [], $attachments = [], $attachmentName = "testing.docx")
    {
        $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
        $email->setSubject($subject);

        if (is_array($to)) {
            foreach ($to as $key => $value) {
                $email->addTo($value);
            }
        } else {
            $email->addTo($to);
        }

        if ($templateData) $email->addDynamicTemplateDatas($templateData);
        $email->setFrom(getenv("MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS"), getenv("MAIL_FROM_NAME"));
        $email->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));

        if ($attachments && is_array($attachments)) {
            foreach ($attachments as $key => $file) {
                $attachment = new Attachment();
                $content = file_get_contents($file["file"]);
                $attachment->setContent($content);
                $attachment->setType(Helper::setFileType($file["file"]));
                $attachment->setFilename($file["name"] . "." . pathinfo($file["file"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                $attachment->setDisposition("attachment");
                $email->addAttachment($attachment);
            }
        }

        try {
            $sendgrid->send($email);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r("Caught exception: " . $e->getMessage()) . "\n";
        }
    }

    private static function setFileType($file): string
    {
        $type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $types = [
            "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
            "pdf" => "application/pdf",
            "zip" => "application/zip",
        ];

        return $types[$type];
    }
```